# Order by de Ng-repeat no refresca con nuevos elemento

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, filtro

Sucede que tengo un ng-repet que me esta recorriendo un array parecido a el sgte:

```
$scope.array = [{sequence:1},{sequence:2},{sequence:3},{sequence:4}]
```

y en html estoy reccorriendo el array y ordenandolo por el atributo sequence

```
ng-repeat="element in array | orderBy: element.sequence"
```

Esto funciona bien la primera vez que cargo, me ordena los elementos de la forma que le he solicitado, el problema esta es cuando añado un nuevo elemento al array, no actualiza la lista, es decir, no vuelve a ordenar, sino que añade al elemento de ultimo

```
$scope.array.push({sequence:-2});
```

El elemento aunque se añade y cargue DOM, no se vuelve a ordenar, como puedo forzar al ng-repeat que vuelva a ordenar los campos.

PD: Lo se, intente con $scope.$apply(); pero surge un error y cuelga el controlador

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes, es que el atributo que quieres dar en el filtro `orderBy` para ser usado con la directiva `ng-repeat`, lo estás entregando mal.

```
{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse : comparator}}
```

El parámetro `expression`, el primero que se le entrega a ese filtro, y con el que va a usar el comparador (sea el integrado con AngularJS, o bien uno propio que tengas a mano) para establecer un orden, recibe:

- O un **string**
- O una **función**
- O un **arreglo de strings y/o funciones**

Tal cual como lo tienes en tu código:

```
ng-repeat="element in array | orderBy: element.sequence"
```

Estás entregando el **número** del atributo `sequence` de cada elemento de tu arreglo.

Entonces, ¿como puedes ordenar? Si estás trabajando con un arreglo de objetos, y lo que quieres es ordenar por un atributo de esos objetos, lo que puedes hacer es entregar un **string** con el nombre del atributo.

Todos los objetos de tu arreglo tienen en común el atributo `sequence`, con ello puedes entregar ese atributo como string al parámetro `expression` del filtro `orderBy`. Tal cual como está, el orden depende de la colección de elementos, y va a ser ascendente (si lo necesitas, lo puedes cambiar).

Con ello el valor que le das a la directiva `ng-repeat` pasa a ser el siguiente:

```
ng-repeat="element in array | orderBy: 'sequence'"
```

¿Funciona? Supongamos que tu arreglo lo voy a poner en una lista no ordenada, en la cual el elemento `<li>` tiene la directiva `ng-repeat` con ese valor.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="element in array | orderBy:'sequence'">
                {{element.sequence}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

En el controlador se va a definir el arreglo, y luego de definirlo, se va a agregar el objeto `{sequence:-2}` al arreglo.

```
angular
    .module("myApp", [])
    .controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope",
        function($scope) {
            $scope.array = [
                { sequence: 1 },
                { sequence: 2 },
                { sequence: 3 },
                { sequence: 4 }
            ];

            $scope.array.push({sequence:-2});
        }
    ]
);
```

El objeto con el valor de `sequence` de -2, va a aparecer primero en la lista, aún si fue agregado al final del arreglo.

Te pongo un snippet con lo que te acabo de señalar, y te agregué un campo de texto para agregar nuevos elementos al arreglo. Al presionar el botón, se crea un objeto con atributo `sequence` y se añade al final del arreglo. Fíjate como el orden lo hace el filtro `orderBy`.

```js
/* Modelo */
angular
  .module("myApp", [])
  .controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    /* Arreglo */
    $scope.array = [
      { sequence: 1 },
      { sequence: 2 },
      { sequence: 3 },
      { sequence: 4 }
    ];
    
    $scope.array.push({sequence:-2});
    
    /* Propiedades/métodos para agregar nuevos elementos */
    $scope.numberToAdd = 0;
        
    $scope.addToArray = function(){
      let obj = {sequence: $scope.numberToAdd};
      $scope.array.push(obj);
      $scope.numberToAdd = 0;
    };
    
    
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <!-- Input para agregar elementos --> 
    <input type="number" placeholder="number" ng-model="numberToAdd"/>
    <button ng-click="addToArray()">
      Añadir
    </button>
    
    <hr/>
    
    <!-- Lista de elementos -->
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="element in array | orderBy:'sequence'">
        {{element.sequence}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Véase tambien**: [orderBy (Documentación de AngularJS)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) (en inglés)

Comment: Excelente explicación, gracias por el tiempo que tomaste en ella, funciono perfecto. Gracias nuevamente